# Increase modal size for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the size of the modal form or rather - have it respond to the content I render there. I am using it to render a form and would prefer to deal with scrolling if required myself.

The form I render probably needs another 50px - just missing the buttons.

So I have tried overriding the .modal styles in my application.css.scss file (Using Rails 3.2)  but the max-height and overflow declerations seems to be overwritten.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same question... chrome says that the height property is accepted (don't get the middle line as overwritten properties) but the computed height remains the same

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/407) might help.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem, you can try:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 800px;
}
```

If you notice the scroll-bars appear only on the body section of the modal dialog, this means that the max-height of only the body needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Setting max-height for the modal-body is not enough, as the bottom of the modal might be pushed out-of-screen.
I had success with:

.modal {
 top:5%;
 bottom:5%; 
}
.modal-body {
 max-height:100%;
 height:85%;
}

Comment: I had to use height: 800px instead of max-height: 800px for it to work.

Answer (score 35):

in Bootstrap 3:

```
.modal-dialog{
  width:whatever
}
```

Comment: given the date in which the question was made, I don't think that TB3 was an issue. But, in any case, thank you for the tip, it's really helpful!

Comment: Just to clarify, if you only want to set the size of a specific modal, one can do this:                                                                                           
                  `#modal_ID .modal-dialog { width: 800px }`

Answer (score 22):

You need to make sure that it is on the #myModal .modal-body element not just #myModal (Seen a few people make this mistake) and you may also want to accomodate for the height change by changing the modals margins.

Answer (score 19):

Using the new CSS3 'vh' (or 'vw' for width) measurement (which sets the height as a fraction of the view port) use:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 80vh; //Sets the height to 80/100ths of the viewport.
}
```

This way, if you're using a responsive framework, like Bootstrap, then you can keep that design in your modals too.

Answer (score 8):

Mixing up two methods for width and height and you have a good hack:

**CSS:**

```
#myModal .modal-body {max-height: 800px;}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('myModal').modal('toggle').css({'width': '800px','margin-left': function () {return -($(this).width() / 2);}})
```

This one is the one I use. It fixs the margin and the scrollbars issues for both width and height but it won't resize the modal to fit its content.

Hope I was of help!

Comment: I tried to get the JQuery to work but I had no luck. Can you help? Where should I use the JQuery?

Comment: max-height on the modal will cause the bottom half to dissapear and isn't scrollable. (as @mcabral suggested)

Answer (score 4):

Using a CSS class (you can also override style - not suggested):

(html)

```
<div class="modal-body custom-height-modal" >
```

(css)

```
.custom-height-modal {
  height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap Large model

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
```

Bootstrap Small model

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer... the thing is that you have overwrite the max-height attribute as well to bootstrap modal can be resized beyond the 500px height limit

Comment: I tried the max-height on the .modal class but it didn't work either. Can you perhaps share the css you used?

Comment: .modal {
  height: 600px;
  max-height: 700px;
}. Just that

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the back overlay is not expanded, thus a part of the popup may be unreachable

Answer (score 1):

Just set ".modal-body" height : 100% it will auto adjust the height as per your content and do put "max-height" as per your screen...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the size parameter:

```
return $modal.open({
  backdrop: 'static',     
  size: 'sm',                   
  templateUrl: "app/views/dialogs/error.html",
  controller: "errorDialogCtrl",
```

Optional sizes

Modals have two optional sizes, available via modifier classes to be placed on a .modal-dialog.

1. default: 600px
2. sm : small, width of 300px
3. lg : large, width of 900px

If you want something different, update the bootstarp.css

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .modal-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }
  .modal-sm {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .modal-xy {  // custom
    width: xxxpx;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 900px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Boostrap > 4 this worked for me:

```
.modal-content{
  width: 1200px;
}
```

a more advanced version:

```
body .modal-content{
  width: 160%!important;
  margin-left: -30%!important;
}
```

here is a codepen:

https://codepen.io/AlfredoMoralesPinzon/pen/xyVOaK

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your modal has an id of `modal1` the following CSS would increase the height of the modal and display any overflow.

```
#modal1 .modal-body{
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few of the above as need to set specific sizes of width and height (to display an image in a modal)and as none above helped me I decided to override the styles and have added the following to the main < div > that has class="modal hide fade in" in it : i.e. added a width to the style tag for the background of the modal.

```
style="display: none; width:645px;"
```

and then added the following 'style' tags to the modal-body:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="height:540px; max-height:540px; width:630px; max-width:630px;">
```

works like a charm now, I'm displaying an image and now it fits perfect.

Comment: Any reason as to why this was downvoted? some feedback as to when you think an error has been made or an untruth / unrelated comment has been made would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
#modal1 .modal 
{ 
     overflow-y: hidden; 
}

#modal1 .modal-dialog 
{ 
     height: 100%; 
     overflow-y: hidden; 
}
```

Note that in my case, I have nested modals, each having controls which require different heights when I toggle control's display inside the **nested modal**, so I could not apply the *max-height*, instead **height:100%** works for me well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the optional bootstrap classes `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` if you want to keep within the responsive framework. And add a clearfix below your form, that may help dependent on your structure.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently trying this and got this correct:
Hope this will be helpful

```
 .modal .modal-body{
        height: 400px;
    }
```

This will adjust height of your model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple method to increase the size of the bootstrap modal:

```
$(".modal-dialog").css("width", "80%");
```

The width of the modal can be specified in terms of percentage of the screen. In the above example i have set it to 80% of my screen width.

Below is an working example of the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal-dialog").css("width", "90%");
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```