# Modal service in AngularJS that allows me to resize the size of the modal popup

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm writing an AngularJS app. I need to open a particular modal popup that is big in size. Is there any AngularJS library out there that allows me to open a modal popup according to my specification ? I have taken a look at AngularStrap : http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##modals, which looks like it doesn't support resizing at all, and AngularUI - Bootstrap : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal, which supports an option for big modal or small modal. I have measured the big modal and it's only 900px in width, which is not that big for me. I want the option to open the modal with specified size at will.

I have seen some answers on here that suggest  to modify the .modal CSS if I want bigger modal popup, but I can't. Other parts of the code did use default modal popup, modify it will cause a mess everywhere else.

Is there any suggestions on how to accomplish this with AngularStrap (preferred library) or AngularUI - Bootstrap ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery.addClass to append a separate class name into that modal. This is precisely the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a separate class name for that modal and make CSS changes using that class name.It won't affect the existing modals.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific ? AngularStrap takes in a template URL for the the modal and other options in the call, but not a class name to replace the default css class for that modal. I know I can change CSS properties of elements within that template, but how I can broaden the size of the modal ? The example on AngularStrap website : http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/1.0/#/modal show CSS class that's not for that modal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416985/increase-modal-size-for-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `windowClass` to my modal service and then appending custom CSS class to this:

```
windowClass: 'app-modal-window'
  .app-modal-window .modal-dialog{width: 375px;
}
```